# Mysql with JSON datatype : Error #2014

Tags: mysql, json, phpmyadmin, mysql-5.7

I have upgraded MySQL from 5.5 to 5.7 recently. I have created one table called `t1` with one column named as `jdoc` with having `json` datatype. I inserted one record over there as like this :-

```
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES('{"key1": "value1", "key2": "value2"}');
```

When I am browsing the table, I am getting the following error.

[image]

When I am going to change the column datatype, its showing the following error.

[image]

FYI -

- MySQL Version - Server version: 5.7.13
- phpMyAdmin Version - 4.6.3 (up to date)

Can anyone please help me out here?

Comment: I can see, someone has marked this question as "Close".. Strange :). Isn't it relevant? I am looking for the solution and thought if anyone can help me on this and that's why added here. If this type of questions are not acceptable, then please let me know, instead of marking it as "Close". I will remove the question from SO on my own.

Comment: same for me 4.6.4